# Scorable with dialog interruption and getting result

Tags: .net, botframework

The [contoso flowers sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/CSharp/demo-ContosoFlowers) shows, how to interrupt flow if a specific word, such as "settings" has been received, and "injects" the setting-dialog.

In all examples I have seen so far that go in this direction, all use the VoidDialog like this:

```
    public async Task PostAsync(IActivity item, object state, CancellationToken token)
    {
        var message = item as IMessageActivity;

        if (message != null)
        {
            var settingsDialog = new SettingsDialog(this.dialogFactory);

            // wrap it with an additional dialog that will restart the wait for
            // messages from the user once the child dialog has finished
            var interruption = settingsDialog.Void<object, IMessageActivity>();

            // put the interrupting dialog on the stack
            this.task.Call(interruption, null);

            // start running the interrupting dialog
            await this.task.PollAsync(token);
        }
    }
```

In my case, I need to get the result form the wrapped dialog (say from the settings dialog), but I was not able to figure out how to do that.

I need to do something similar like the [DeleteProfileScorable](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/blob/master/CSharp/Library/Microsoft.Bot.Builder/Dialogs/DeleteProfileScorable.cs), but I want to ask the user if he really wants to proceed, so I created a dialog asking for that. I need to get the result (okay or not) outside from that dialog, because `stack.Reset()` does not seem to work from inside a dialog ("stack is empty" error).

I also tried to add a resume handler here `this.task.Call(interruption, MyResumeHandler);` but this gives me this error:

> IDialog method execution finished with multiple resume handlers
>   specified through IDialogStack.

Calling the dialog directly also causes this error.

I also copied the source from VoidDialog and alter it to my needs, but I always struggle with the same kind errors.

I guess the solution could be very easy, but afters a few hours of try and error, I hope someone can help me out?

Comment: Did you get a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

The solution here should be to interrupt with another dialog that calls the setting dialog and accepts the result.  The result can be something arbitrary or trivial just to get you to where you need to be in the stack.

Comment: The problem is, I need to get the result (bool, if aborting is ok or not) from within the the scorable, because only there I'm able to call stack.Reset() without an exception.